# init.d script only running on shutdown and not startup

Tags: linux

I have a script I've adapted from [this post](https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html). It's supposed to have sections that run on start and shutdown, however only the shutdown section is run.

I'm also having difficulty finding docs related to this... probably don't have the right search

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/helloworld
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    touch /home/pi/hiii
    ;;
  stop)
    touch /home/pi/byeee
    ;;
  *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

What I've done
1. saved the script to `/etc/init.d/helloworld`
2. made it executable with `chmod 755`
3. registered it with `sudo update-rc.d helloworld defaults`

There was another [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/449805/init-d-script-not-running-on-startup) however it did not fix it for me

Comment: Is `/home/pi/` in any way peculiar? (e.g. it gets mounted late or there is some encryption involved).

Comment: nope, os is basically clean. Unlikely to be having a strange config issue. I think I'm starting to catch onto the problem though, update-rc.d doesn't seem to be current... just starting to look into systemd